# Prove that ${x_n}$'s set of accumulation points is exactly $[A, B]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

Given that $\underline\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = A < B = \overline\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n$, and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$，prove that ${x_n}$'s set of accumulation points is exactly $[A, B]$.

It's easy to find two convergent subsequences of ${x_n}$, which converges to $A$ and $B$ respectively. However, doing so would render $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} - x_n) = 0$, one of the two known conditions, useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix an element $x \in [A,B]$.  Fix an $\epsilon > 0$.  Because $x_{n+1} - x_n \to 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n \geq N \implies |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$.

Now, choose an $n_0 > N$ such that $|x_{n_0} - A| < \epsilon$.  There exists an $n_1 > n_0$ such that $|x_{n_1} - B| < \epsilon$.  Consider the elements $x_{n_0},x_{n_0+1},\dots,x_{n_1 - 1},x_{n_1} = x_{n_0 + K}$.  We note that for each $i$, we have $|x_{n_0 + i} - x_{n_0 + i - 1}| < \epsilon$.  Note, then, that the interval $(x_{n_0 + i} - \epsilon,x_{n_0+i} + \epsilon)$ contains both $x_{n_0+i-1}$ and $x_{n_0+i+1}$ for $i = 1,\dots,K-1$. Of course, $(x_{n_0} - \epsilon,x_{n_0} + \epsilon)$ contains $A$, and $(x_{n_0 + K} - \epsilon,x_{n_0+K} + \epsilon)$ contains $B$.

Use this to conclude that
$$
[A,B] \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^K (x_{n_0 + i} - \epsilon, x_{n_0 + i} + \epsilon)
$$
Thus, our arbitrary $x$ from the start satisfies $x \in (x_{n_0 + i} - \epsilon, x_{n_0 + i} + \epsilon)$ for some $i$.  That is, $|x - x_{n_0 + i}| < \epsilon$.  In other words: for any $x \in [A,B]$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $n$ (in this case $n = n_0 + i$) such that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

So, $x$ is an accumulation point.  So, *every* element of $[A,B]$ is an accumulation point, as desired.

Comment: "..., there exists an $n$ (in this case $n = n_0 + i$) such that $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$." I think we have to ensure that $0 < |x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @SunQingyao as I say two sentences earlier, we have $|x - x_{n_0  + i}| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I mean, what if $x$ is _exactly_ $x_{n_0+i}$ for some $i$? [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point), a point $x$ in $X$ is a **accumulation point** of $S$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ _different from $x$ itself_.

Comment: Now I understand.  At the very least, it suffices to note that $x + \epsilon$ will be another "candidate accumulation point" for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.